# Continually grab images from camera for processing

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I'm trying to use Camera.MAUI to grab images from the camera continually and send each image for processing to another library which will try to detect barcodes (I know Camera.MAUI also has barcode detection but it doesn't work well).

I've added the CameraView control to my main page but cannot find any image grabbed events to hook to. How can I send images from the camera to my other code?

```
<cv:CameraView x:Name="CameraView" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="200"
                CamerasLoaded="CameraView_CamerasLoaded" />
```

My code-behind so far:

```
private void CameraView_CamerasLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CameraView.Camera = CameraView.Cameras.First();

    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        await CameraView.StopCameraAsync();
        var startSuccess = await CameraView.StartCameraAsync();

        if (startSuccess == Camera.MAUI.CameraResult.Success)
        {
            CameraView.AutoSnapShotAsImageSource = true;
            CameraView.AutoSnapShotSeconds = 1;
            CameraView.AutoSnapShotFormat = Camera.MAUI.ImageFormat.PNG;
            CameraView.BarCodeOptions = new BarcodeDecodeOptions() { PureBarcode = true, ReadMultipleCodes = true, TryHarder = true };
            CameraView.TakeAutoSnapShot = true;
        }
    });
}
```